How to Access OpenAI chat with .Net Core 8
                public class OpenAiService : IOpenAiService
            {
                private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
                private readonly string _openAiApiKey;

                public OpenAiService(HttpClient httpClient, string openAiApiKey)
                {
                    _httpClient = httpClient;
                    _openAiApiKey = openAiApiKey;

                }

                public async Task<string> GetNextStoryAsync(List<Message> messages)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var request = new
                        {
                            model = "gpt-4o-mini",
                            messages = messages
                        };

                        // Serialize the request object to JSON using System.Text.Json
                        var content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(request), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {_openAiApiKey}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"Bearer {_openAiApiKey}");

                        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", content);

                        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            return result;
                        }
                        return "Blank Result";
                    }
                    catch (HttpRequestException e)
                    {
                        throw new Exception($"HttpRequestException occurred: {e.Message}");

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        throw new Exception($"An error occurred while communicating with OpenAI: {e.Message}");
                    }
                }
            }

I get a 404 not found. The key is printed correctly. I am confused about the model being used, hopefully it's the correct model as I have a subscription.

Are you able to call the "list models" endpoint to see if that model is available? https://api.openai.com/v1/models
